# How to make custom circular clipper shape like Notched Curve with Edges Inside in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been trying to make a custom clipper curve as shown in image. Let me know if anyone can help me figure out how to make that curve?

**// View Part**

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0,
                      12.0),
                  height: 60.0,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(16)),
                      child: CustomCurvedShape()),
                ),
            )
```

**// Clipper Part**

```
final AVATAR_RADIUS = 30.0;
class CustomCurveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {

    // final shapeBounds = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height - AVATAR_RADIUS);
    final shapeBounds = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    //1
    // final centerAvatar = Offset(shapeBounds.center.dx, shapeBounds.bottom);
    final centerAvatar = Offset(shapeBounds.center.dx, shapeBounds.bottom);
    //2
    final avatarBounds = Rect.fromCircle(center: centerAvatar, radius: AVATAR_RADIUS);

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(shapeBounds.left, shapeBounds.top) //3
      ..lineTo(shapeBounds.bottomLeft.dx, shapeBounds.bottomLeft.dy)
      ..arcTo(avatarBounds, -pi, pi, false) //5
      ..lineTo(shapeBounds.bottomRight.dx, shapeBounds.bottomRight.dy) //6
      ..lineTo(shapeBounds.topRight.dx, shapeBounds.topRight.dy) //7
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

class CustomCurvedShape extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: CustomCurveClipper(),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 60.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: redActiveColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0))
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Not able to figure out how to make following curve design? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]